# ANID2 returns null

Tags: windows-phone-8

I try to get the ANID2 in my Windows Phone 8 app.

But it always returns null.

My code is:

```
object anid;

DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("ANID2", out anid);
```

if I try GetValue instead of TryGetValue("ANID2")
I get the following Exception:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

The Capability "ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER" is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I used "DeviceExtendedProperties" for ANID2. But you have to use UserExtendedProperties.GetValue("ANID2")